# Causality and intention : how to use "out of"

Tags: grammaticality

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> Unfortunately this experiment about superconductive circuits was interrupted **out of** some political troubles.

The person who wrote the sentence above has learned that "out of" is not grammatical here. But why is it ungrammatical here?

Answer (score 2):

'**Out of** etc.' is a mismatch with the preceding verb '**interrupted**' (it just doesn't describe how that verb operates) for which it is supposed to introduce a descriptive clause. The correct preposition in this context is '**by**' - together with some other necessary changes we would have:

**Unfortunately, these experiments on superconductive circuits were interrupted by political troubles.**